# ORACLE APEX PL/SQL dynamic content, inserting ID of clicked item to table

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, apex

I've written collapsible list in PL/SQL dynamic content using HTML and JavaScript.

[my collapsible list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssC1q.jpg)

Is there any way to insert ID of clicked item into table?
Clickable fields are buttons.

Thanks

edit

```
    for i in c loop
```

```
        HTP.P('<button type="button" class="collapsible">
        'i.Header of list'
        ('</button><div class="content"><p>'i.content of list'</p></div>'));
```

```
    end loop;
```

Comment: Can you add the html of one of the list items to the question ? That content can be rendered in many different ways

Comment: Have a look at [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69071447/add-a-dynamic-action-to-a-button-created-dynamically), it explains how to add a custom event to a button on a table. In this answer the table is a report, but same logic can be applied to dynamic content

Comment: @KoenLostrie code added to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example based on the EMP/DEPT sample dataset.

**Step 1**: Create pl/sql dynamic content region. Make sure the button has a (1) a custom class to capture the click event and (2) a data attribute to uniquely define the row.

```
for i in (SELECT * FROM emp) loop 
  htp.p(apex_string.format('</button><div class="my-button-js content" data-empno="%0"><p>%1</p></div>',i.empno,i.ename));
end loop;
```

**Step 2:** create a (hidden) page item to hold the identifier of the row you clicked, in my case P104_EMPNO.

**Step 3:** Create a dynamic action to set the value to P104_EMPNO to the value empno of the row button you clicked in the report.

- Selection Type: JQuery Selector
- JQuery Selector: .my-button-js

True Action 1:

- Action: "Set Value"
- Set Type: "Javascript Expression"
- Javascript Expression: `this.triggeringElement.dataset['empno']`
- Affected Element: P104_EMPNO

True Action 2:

- Action: "Execute Javascript Code", Code: `$.event.trigger("mybuttonclicked");`

**Step 4:** Create a dynamic action to fire on the custom event you fired in True Action 2 of Step 3.

- Event: Custom
- Custom Event: mybuttonclicked
- Selection Type: "Javascript Expression"
- Javascript Expression: `document`

True Action 1:

- Action: Execute Server-side Code
- Language: PL/SQL
- Code: `UPDATE EMP SET sal = sal * 1.1 WHERE empno = :P104_EMPNO;`
- Items to Submit: P104_EMPNO