# Asynchronous Listener error using Dynamic Action on Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using an interactive report, with a static ID of people_picker.

It has a few columns which also have static_id values which I reference in Javascript.

I have a dynamic action which is set to "Click" using a JQUERY selector.

The javascript action in the dynamic action is as below.

```
var prid = apex.item('P2_DES_ASSIGNED_TO_PRID').getValue();
var display_name = apex.item('P2_DES_ASSIGNED_TO_EMAIL').getValue();
var email = apex.item('P2_DES_ASSIGNED_TO_NAME').getValue();

console.log("Before------")
console.log("prid: " + prid)
console.log("prid: " + display_name)
console.log("prid: " + email)

prid = $(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('td[headers="people_picker_prid"]').text();
display_name = $(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('td[headers="people_picker_display_name"]').text();
email= $(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('td[headers="people_picker_email"]').text();

console.log("After------")
console.log("prid: " + prid)
console.log("prid: " + display_name)
console.log("prid: " + email)

apex.item('P2_DES_ASSIGNED_TO_PRID').setValue(prid);
apex.item('P2_DES_ASSIGNED_TO_EMAIL').setValue(email);
apex.item('P2_DES_ASSIGNED_TO_NAME').setValue(display_name);
```

The JQUERY selector is in the dynamic action is:

> #people_picker td

There is an Confirm step in the dynamic action which needs to run after the javascript writes the values.

[image]

Now sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt.

If I put the CONFIRM step above the javascript step, it works (but this isnt what I need). So I know the javascript is working and setting page items and session state.  Sometimes it works anyway, without intervention - but fails quite often.

The error I am getting is:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous
> response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a
> response was received

The interactive report is in an inline dialog box.

Comment: Version of apex ?

Comment: 23.1 version @KoenLostrie

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd try - however I'm by no means a javascript expert. I'd create 2 different dynamic actions. The first one (DA1) would execute the javascript code that you have now and the second one (DA2) would have all the other true actions.

At the end of the javascript in DA1 add an `$.event.trigger` call

DA2 should fire on that custom event.

An example of how to do this can be found in step 3 and 4 of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73858502/oracle-apex-pl-sql-dynamic-content-inserting-id-of-clicked-item-to-table) post.

Now as from apex 22.2 you can throttle and debounce dynamic actions. I'd try setting a debounce of 500 ms on the 2nd dynamic action.

Again... this is just a guess but worth a try. Good luck !