# Oracle Apex - JS Dynamic Action to Enable/Disable item

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a page with 3 different items:

list of values: resource
list of values: status
Text field (which will be converted to a hidden item later on)

Whenever the user selects a checkbox on the IR, the row id value of the selected row goes into the Text Field item. It concatenates as necessary.
Thing is, I'm trying to add a dynamic action that enables or disables a button based on these 3 items described initially, like this:

Dyn Action: on change of my 3 items (on true)
Javascript expression to enable:

```
$v("my_text_item").length > 2 && ($v("my_resource_lov") != "" || $v( 
"my_status_lov" ) != "" )
```

Javascript expression to disable:

```
$v("my_text_item").length > 2 && ($v("my_resource_lov") == "" && $v( 
"my_status_lov" ) == "" )
```

But it doesn't work.
I tested it out on the console and it runs perfectly (true or false when needed).
Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the button to be disabled when (1) one of the 3 events occurs and (2) a combination of values meets a certain condition.
There are 2 ways to do this - well probably more but here are 2.

The "old" way. Create an on-change dynamic action for each of the 3 events with a disable action that has a javascript condition you described. Downside is that you have an identical action for all 3 dynamic actions which could be a maintenance issue.

The "modern" way. Create an on-change dynamic action for each of the 3 events with a javascript true action that triggers a javascript event.
Create a 2nd dynamic action that acts on the event with a disable action that has a javascript condition you described. A similar technique is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69071447/add-a-dynamic-action-to-a-button-created-dynamically/69071815#69071815).